# AspNetCore 6 - No connection string named - could be found in the application config file

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, configuration, connection-string

The web app that I'm testing is running on .Net Core 6 with data layer (library) on reference. I installed entity framework in the data layer and automatically added an App.config with

But when I run the startup project (web app) an error shows

```
No connection string named '' could be found in the application config file.
```

I already added the connection string in appsettings.js of the web app.

What's the reason for the error message and how can I configure the Program.cs file?

Comment: Did you install Entity Framework or Entity Framework Core? Did you follow the documentations recommended approach for installing EF or EF Core?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this approach by using `Scaffold-DbContext` in the data access layer